# Posts and Pages not showing on admin, but showing in theme

Tags: themes, admin, database

I've just transferred a WordPress install over from and old IIS server set up by our client, to our new Lunix based VPS. Whether that is relevant or not, i'm not sure.

I've changed all the usual settings and database options i'd usual do on moving a website to a new/live server environment.. This has worked perfectly other than the data doesn't show in the WordPress admin specifically, but does if you visit www.lenstec.co.uk. That suggest the data is being successfully pulled in as it normally would.

My initial thoughts are that this may be a global variable somewhere within the theme that WordPress does not like?

Unfortunately, i've check through my function file and corresponding theme files and not come across anything.

Can anyone suggest something I may have missed?

Comment: Please provide [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). My first thought is "timeout". The backend tends to be heavier than the front.

Comment: '
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post_format() in /var/www/vhosts/lenstec.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php on line 551 ' happens to be showing when on the admin once debug is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Core code trying to use a Core function. You have almost certainly had a problem with the transfer.

1. Very carefully, re-upload all of the files. I expect some file is
   missing or corrupt.
2. And make sure that [all of your permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress) are correct.

It would probably be a good idea to disable plugins and switch to a default theme as well. Since you can't get into the backend you will need to remove or rename the theme and plugin folders via FTP.

Since you just transfered, I am assuming that you have good backups.

Comment: You were right, whatever happened during the original copy, messed up the site. Some dodgy copy down of files. As a note after backing up all files, i updated wordpress and away to go. Thanks for the help anyways.